# Why do characters in The Departed put the ‘F’ word in the middle of their words?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

These are words spoken by characters in The Departed with the ‘F’ word inserted in the middle of them:

> Whoop-de-**fu_king**-do
>
> LA-di-**fu_king**-da
>
> abra-**fu_king**-cadabra
>
> Sigmund **fu_king** Freud
>
> Mr. **Fu_king**-Genius-Who-Didn't Even-Graduate-From-the-Academy?

Why do characters in [The Departed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Departed) put the ‘F’ word in the middle of their words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more an English Language question than one to do with the movie, though it's certainly in-character for the movie's dialog.

It's known as [expletive infixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_infixation#Rules_of_formation), and is a common idiomatic way of expressing. It works best on longer words and has known patterns as to where the infixation occurs.
It's a sub-set of [tmesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis)

> a word compound that is divided into two parts, with another word infixed between the parts, thus constituting a separate word compound. In a broader sense, tmesis is a recognizable phrase (such as a phrasal verb) or word that is divided into two parts, with one or more words interpolated between the parts, thus creating a separate phrase.

Is it really?
Abso-fucking-lutely.

Comment: More simply: that’s how some people actually talk.